# fillAfter Not Work In Android XML

Tags: android

I want to fade in a shape and hide it. I use fillAfter="true" in my xml file. But it not work.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >
    <alpha
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 7):

Inside the `<set tag, use ...`

code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
   android:fillAfter="true" >
   <alpha
       android:toAlpha="0"
       android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

or setFillAfter and setFillEnable is the answer you need.

Answer (score 1):

> If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed
>   will persist when it is finished.

However unintuitively an animation on Android does not actually animate the View itself on which you are aplying the animation, rather it animates a bitmap representation of the View.
So after an animation the View goes back to being how it was before the animation - `setFillAfter` cannot help you with that, **because in this situation  you should set the properties of the View to be same as the animated representation.**

Answer (score 0):

make sure that any other animations on this view or all inner views not working when your new animation tries to "fill after"